# DirectShow - Microsoft LifeCam Studio - RBG24 format lost

Tags: webcam, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net, graphedit

I'm using DirectShowNet in C#. I've been developing an application to work with webcams to display video, change resolution, and take pictures (either Still pin or from the Capture stream). I've been testing it on 2 different machines (Win 7 64-bit & Win 8 64-bit) and with the internal webcams on those machines (they are laptops) and 2 other webcams, Logitech C920 and Microsoft LifeCam Studio.

One day, the LifeCam Studio stopped working on my Win 8 machine. Using GraphEditPlus, checking the VideoFormats for the Capture pin, I notice that, mysteriously, the RGB24 formats are no longer listed. I have written my application to use only 24-bit color format. Only YUY2 16-bit formats are listed. If I check the same webcam on my Win 7 machine, I see both the YUY2 and the RGB24 formats being listed. Previously, my Win 8 machine did list both of these formats.

The question is, **what could cause DirectShow to change the list of VideoFormats for the Capture pin?** So far, I've noticed that changing driver versions makes a huge difference for webcams in what pins they support, but I haven't seen them change video formats like this. As far as I know, I have not updated the drivers for the webcam on either machine.

Here are the driver versions for both machines.

---

### LifeCam Studio - Windows 7 - 64-bit

[image: LifeCam Studio - Windows 7 - 64-bit]

### LifeCam Studio - Windows 8 - 64-bit

[image: LifeCam Studio - Windows 8 - 64-bit]

Comment: Windows updated rolled out a driver update that does not support 24-bit RGB anymore? It should be not a big deal to get `YUY2` converted to RGB by the way, and since it is a problem for you now odds are high you are doing something in a shaky way.

Comment: The reason only 24-bit formats are supported is because I'm connecting a SampleGrabber with a hardcoded media format of MediaSubType.RGB24. This format seems to work with any of the 24-bit formats properly. It would make my solution much more complex if I have to re-create the sample grabber depending on the resolution the user selects. Plus, it makes my API much simpler if when a dev gets the supported video formats, it only gives 1 set of resolutions, instead of multiple ones depending on the color format.

Comment: Under normal conditions, if camera supports YUY2 only and you set SG to use 24-bit RGB, the converter/decoder is supplied automatically (so that many even don't realize it's there - it just works).

Comment: Agreed. But, it still doesn't answer why my machine does not have the same list of video formats for the Capture pin on the same webcam. I basically just want the same drivers for each so I don't have to deal with them being different.

Comment: The drivers are apparently different. DirectShow user mode filters only forward formats drivers expose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to get the formats back. I went into device manager and found the "Microsoft LifeCam Studio" device. I uninstalled it and hit the checkbox to "Also delete the driver for this device". After that, I refreshed device manager, and when the device was found, it had the name "Microsoft® LifeCam Studio(TM)", but then changed to "Microsoft LifeCam Studio". That made me realize that it automatically updated the driver.

As you notice in my Win 8 screenshot above, the button "Roll Back Driver" is enabled. This means that the driver was updated at some point. I proceeded to roll back the driver, which changed the name back to "Microsoft® LifeCam Studio(TM)".

Now, in GraphEditPlus, the device lists YUY2, MJPG (24-bit), and M420 (12-bit) video formats for the Capture pin. This seems to be what I have had in the past. It works properly with my application now since a 24-bit format is available.

Overall, **Microsoft removed some of the DirectShow functionality of the device when they made the Windows 8 driver**. This old driver is from 2006 and works fantastically with Windows 8. I'm assuming it is one built into the OS that was carryover from old Windows OS's.

Here is a screenshot of the working driver for others that would like more video formats available for the LifeCam Studio in Windows 8.

---

### LifeCam Studio - Windows 8 - 64-bit - Original Driver

[image]